# Faster way to achieve document conversion/preview task

Tags: docx, pandoc

I created win forms app to convert docx to html using pandoc, and a web browser control
to display the html file. This application is much needed for my colleagues in the university,
to preview docx files since we dont have MS Office access any more...

I tested this at my PC and it is working fine on each item click in the listbox,
it loads the preview in webbrowser quicky. But I just want to make it more quick, is there
any recommendations to make it faster (I can provide full code if needed), but the following
is the main listbox selected item changed event:

Also tell me which one is faster from: setting `wb.DocumentText` as blank or navigate it to about:blank page

```
  private void lbFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                wb.DocumentText = "";

                // Two string lists
                SelectedFile = AllFiles[lbFiles.SelectedIndex];
                NameOnly = AllNamesOnly[lbFiles.SelectedIndex];

                if (NameOnly.EndsWith(".txt") || NameOnly.EndsWith(".docx"))
                {
                    #region MediaFolder
                    if (Directory.Exists("MF")) Directory.Delete("MF", true);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("MF");
                    #endregion

                    string cmd = "pandoc --extract-media ./MF \"" + SelectedFile + "\" -o " + "output.html";

                    File.WriteAllText("BatchFile.bat", cmd);

                    StartHidden("BatchFile.bat"); //Process object with: ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; and with 3 seconds exit wait

                    wb.Navigate(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.html");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            
        }
```

Comment: wordpad doesnt show the docx preview in file explorer. I already tried that. And we have got WPS office, basically editing is not a problem. The requirement is to check multiple documents in preview mode using click or arrow key movment like it was possible with MS office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried hard with various solutions.

Most of them were not free, so were not useable, using pendoc as in OP, was not
feasible since it doesn't support the variety of fonts and formats

After going through many possible alternatives (Gembox, Spire.Doc, etc.),
I finally moved to Syncfusion community edition it is already free and its libraries allow to convert all major word processor based formats and its result was same as other non-free solutions. And works faster then pandoc.

Another thing to note is, I switched from WebBrowser to CefSharp as well, as its faster and lighter than WebBrowser, and it works better for pdf file
previews in browser (you can use zoom level, page number as part of URL)